# Filtering GetData() dataset method in visual studio c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dataset

I use the Dataset object as my Orm in c#, but it only generates GetData,Update, Delete methods, which is cool. There is need sometimes for my to have methods like GetById, usually i write a stored procedure and attach to the specific table. Is there a way i can bypass writing this method. Is it possible that at the time i am consuming GetData() i could write filter it by ID, without needing to create another method?

edit
Code sample

```
  OnlineShopTableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter productsDataset= new OnlineShopTableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter();

Datatable singleProductRow = productsDataset.GetData.filterById(productId);  //this is where the filter logic is expected
```

Comment: if u have tried with code, place the code with your question.. It would be better to understand..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rowfilter like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.RowFilter = "ID = 1";              //where ID is the column name
```

Comment: Thank you @thevan, what if i intend to connect an objectdatasource in my aspx page, directly to the dataset, how do i do this?